# Modify SkLearn RandomForestClassifier to use different bootstrapping method

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

Following recent advances in financial Machine Learning (Marcos Lopez del Prado, 2018), i've implemented a the "sequential bootstrapping" described in the book mentioned above. I would like to modify the Scikit-learn class RandomForestClassifier to take predefined series of samples produced by the "sequential bootstrapping" in a manner that maximises the uniqueness of samples. I've not been able to get any guidance on how to modify said class. Any thoughts?

If trying to do thru a custom class (CustomRF) that inherits the base class RandomForestClassifier i've notice that if we check which methods RandomForestClassifier inherits from with help function the output is the following:

```
 Method resolution order:
   CustomRF
   sklearn.ensemble._forest.RandomForestClassifier
   sklearn.ensemble._forest.ForestClassifier
   sklearn.base.ClassifierMixin
   sklearn.ensemble._forest.BaseForest
   sklearn.base.MultiOutputMixin
   sklearn.ensemble._base.BaseEnsemble
   sklearn.base.MetaEstimatorMixin
   sklearn.base.BaseEstimator
   builtins.object
```

And if we check whats inherit from `sklearn.ensemble._forest.BaseForest` we get:

```
apply(self,X)
decision_path(self,X)
fit(self,X,y,sample_weight = False)
```

so those are the methods we can modify. If we get deeper on those three methods and focus on `fit(self,X,y,sample_weight = False)`
It interacts with the private methods `_parallel_build_trees` that calls `_generate_sample_indices` (method shown bellow):

```
def _generate_sample_indices(random_state, n_samples, n_samples_bootstrap):
"""
Private function used to _parallel_build_trees function."""

random_instance = check_random_state(random_state)
sample_indices = random_instance.randint(0, n_samples, n_samples_bootstrap)

return sample_indices
```

That is where the samples are drawn randomly. What i would like is to force those sample_indices to the ones produced by "sequential bootstrap". So going back to the CustomRF class how i can modify the fit() model in order to end up with a `_generate_sample_indices` modification?

Comment: Any updates on this question ?

Answer (score 0):

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/index.html gives an overview of how to extend scikit-learn.

I suggest that you build scikit-learn from source.

```
git clone git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git  # add --depth 1 if your connection is slow
cd scikit-learn
```

Then you can build it via conda or build it manually (bit harder).

To build via conda do:

```
conda create -n sklearn-env -c conda-forge python=3.9 numpy scipy cython
conda activate sklearn-env
```

Now install a compiler with OpenMP support for your platform. See instructions for Windows, macOS, Linux and FreeBSD. (see this link: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#building-from-source building from source point number 4)

Then build the project with pip in edible mode

```
pip install --verbose --no-build-isolation --editable .
```

Now check that the installed scikit-learn has a version number ending with
.dev0:

```
python -c "import sklearn; sklearn.show_versions()"
```

You can now import your build of sklearn in python. If you change the source code of the modules you have to rebuild the project with pip.

Some tips:

- Start simple, the code base is very complicated. Try to edit some simple things and see what changes.
- Make sure you understand the baseclasses well because you will probably have to extend these with your own classes.
- You will probably have to write cython and this is a bit difficult, try to learn some cython first.

Comment: Hi Areobe. Thanks for your quick response. Before trying to do it as you suggest i have one question. It can't be done  inheriting the base class RandomForestClassifier and modifying its methods? If you inherit the class and see its resolution you can see that sklearn.ensemble._forest has the methods that provide the indices of the samples from the bootstrap method:
https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/_modules/sklearn/ensemble/_forest.html

Comment: @JavierCSalaverri that could work I'm not sure if these methods get overwritten in the subclasses or not.

Comment: If i create a CustomRF class that inherits the RandomForestClassifier class. how can i modify methods that said class inherits from sklearn.ensemble._forest?
thanks for the attention Areobe